# for loop not working

Tags: shell

My for loop is not working:

```
#!/bin/sh
for (( count=2; count < 5; count++))
do
  parameter=$count
  echo $parameter
done
```

Error:

> ./new.sh: syntax error at line 2: `(' unexpected

Answer (score 3):

The `(( ))` construct is not POSIX. You must use an interpreter like `#!/bin/bash` if you want this.

The POSIX alternative for this would be:

```
for count in 2 3 4; do
  parameter=$count
  echo $parameter
done
```

Or

```
for count in $(seq 2 4); do
  parameter=$count
  echo $parameter
done
```

The latter being more scalable at the cost of calling an external binary (`seq`)

Comment: If i want the condition like "for (( count=2; count < NumberOfTimes; count++)) " and NumberOfTimes is dynamic...then what to do?

Comment: @sap: if using `bash` then exactly what you put. If using a POSIX shell then `for count in $(seq 2 $NumberOfTimes); do`

Comment: #!/bin/sh

for count in $(seq 2 4);
do
parameter=$count
echo $parameter
done
                    Error:./test.sh: syntax error at line 3: `$' unexpected

Comment: @sap, in other words, use `#!/bin/bash` not `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: @sap what if you did `for count in \`seq 2 4\``